# propositional logical Symbols

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Consider the following four propositions:

s means ’”Samir comes to the party”
c means ’”Callum comes to the party”
r means ’”Ruby comes to the party”
j means ’”Jay comes to the party”.

”If Jay comes to the party, then, if Callum doesn't come then both Samir and Ruby come".

i am struggling as I should express above sentence with propositional logical Symbols

so , my answer is  (j→(¬c→(s∧r))

Comment: Looks right to me

Comment: This looks good, although it is worth noting that $\Rightarrow$, implication, is not often the same thing as "if-then" in ordinary language, as the whole expression is always true when the antecedent is false. This is to be contrasted with $\Leftrightarrow$, bi-directional implication ("if and only if"), in which the whole expression is true only when both operands share a value. This is closer to what we often mean in language.